# RDLC: how to add page break in the table

Tags: rdlc

I have problem with rdlc for payment schedule. Schedule can be 48 or 60 rows. 
I have some text before schedule and after. I managed to fit 48 rows on one page but then I have problem with 60 rows schedule. It prints on first page only text what is before table and schedule table is printed on the next page. But I don't want to be first page empty. If 60 rows don't fit on one page, it breaks table normally. But if i make row hight bigger 48 rows table jumps to second page.
I need page break in the middle of the table or something like that. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: Resolved this problem by changing row font size conditionally.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? break exactly in half? fit as much as it can and then continue on second page? "Jam" all in one page regardless? depending on what you want, you may take different approach.

Comment: I wanted fit as much as it can and then continue on second page.

Answer (score 0):

Set KeepTogether property of the table or group inside the table, depending how you are doing it, to **False**, It is usually True by default:

[image]

And then set RepeatOnNewPage property of the table or group header to **True**:

[image]